# ng-click not firing anything at all

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm having what seems to be a rather simple problem in my first full Angular application. I have some code:

```
<div class="button-bar bar-dark" ng-controller="FeedController">
<a class="button" onclick="console.log('..');" ng-click="console.log('...');">Click Me</a>
</div>
```

At first I thought I was having an issue with $scope, and **EVERY** single question related to ng-click I found on SO about it not firing leads back to that, but as you can see from the above code (after I changed from my function to a simple `console.log`), my issue is simpler - *ng-click just doesn't do anything*. There's no error. The onclick fires, but ng-click does not.

What's weirdest is that in that same page, I have the following that DOES work:

```
<div class="list" id="rssnews" ng-controller="FeedController">
            <a ng-click="doSomething('{{entry.link}}')">
            <span ng-bind-html="entry.content"></span></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Unless you have bound `window.console` to `$scope.console`, your ng-click will not fire.

Comment: Do you have console errors... both your samples above won't do anything. `ng-click="doSomething(entry.link)"`

Comment: No errors whatsoever.

(doSomething is defined in another file, as is FeedController)

Comment: @Thirk `ng-click="console.log('...');"` is not going to work anyway. Plus most probably your controller is not getting attached to your this template. Please share your js code where you are defining controller and other files which are somehow connected with controller.

Answer (score 1):

Try calling functions in both events, the following works for me:

```
<a class="button" onclick="nativeFn()" ng-click="ngFn()">Click Me</a>
```

Declare the one function in the same file

```
function nativeFn() {
    alert("nativeFn is triggered!");
};
```

and the other one in your controller

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.ngFn = function () {
        alert("ngFn is triggered!");
    };
}
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me realize I've been chasing ghosts all day... I forgot to camelCase my function name and have been trying to call it in camelCase. oops...